# How to install dltpy library via python anaconda

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, installation

I'm developing an application via **spyder** that can read and convert **dlt** files into a txt extension file, therefore I need to add **dltpy** library to spyder

I found a site https://pypi.org/project/dltpy/ in which it provided commands( you'll find below) to install the "dltpy" library. however, I wasn't I able to install it via anaconda.

**INSTALLATION:**

git clone git+https://github.com/Equidamoid/dltpy
(cd dltpy; git checkout native-dltreader)

pip install --user ./dltpy

**Is it possible to install a github library into spyder?**

Thank you for your help.

Comment: If a package you want isn't available on a `conda` channel, you should be able to install it using `pip`. Preferably you should create and activate a conda env with the packages you want to use, rather than trying to install into the base environment. Did you try the commands in your question and it didn't work?

Comment: yes, I tried it using conda prompt and did not work

Comment: Did you create and activate a new environment first, containing the other packages you want to use? i.e. `conda create -n myenv package1 package2 ...` then `activate myenv`?

Comment: No, i didn't know how to create one, I'll try to create it then.
thank you.